# How do I use PHP Function preg_replace() in naming a .txt file after a site URL

Tags: php, preg-replace, fopen

How can I name a **txt** file after a site URL without the preceding `https://` or `http://` as in: `www.google.com.txt`? 
I think I might be getting it wrong here: `fopen($sitenameWithoutHTTP.".txt, "w");`

Below is the way I'm trying to address that:

```
<?php
//
@mkdir("result", 0755); 
@chdir("result");
$link = $sitename;
$sitename = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $sitenameWithoutHTTP);
$resultfile = fopen($sitenameWithoutHTTP.".txt", "w");
//
?>
```

Thanks for helping find a fix.

Comment: The site name give an example of what you starting with and what you want it to look like.

Comment: Uh, the third parameter of `preg_replace` should be swapped with the variable on the left side of the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you achieve what you intended!

```
<?php
$siteName = 'https://www.google.com';

$siteNameWithoutHttps = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $siteName);

// print_r($siteNameWithoutHttps);

$resultFile = fopen($siteNameWithoutHttps.".txt", "w");

// run a check
if($resultFile == true) {
echo "success";
} else {
echo "failed";
}
```

The expected result for the commented *print_r* above should be:

```
www.google.com
```

Comment: Do visit [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp) and the official [PHP website](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ['http','https',':','/','?','&','#','.'];

$sitename = str_replace($arr, '', $sitenameWithoutHTTP);
```

also you can use [`base64_encode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php), or use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$HOST = parse_url($sitenameWithoutHTTP, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

and if you need to save real URL and get it again I see best way with using Md5 hash

```
$fileName = md5($sitenameWithoutHTTP).'.txt';
```

can get it again `file.php/?getFile2url=[httpLink]`

```
header('Location: '. Md5($_GET['getFile2url']).'.txt');
exit;
```